# Setting up svn manually for the first time - Permission denied - txn-current-lock

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions, svn

Following various tutorials, I've got svn running via a xinetd.d configuration for svnserve. I'm trying to checkout locally to test the svn setup, but when I try to commit any files to the svn repo, I get a Permission denied error. I created an svn group and added my user account to it, and then I made the svn directory owned by the svn group and set file permissions to 774, but still I get this error.

What could be going wrong? I seem to be able to checkout just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check under which user svnserve runs

```
ps faux|grep svnserve
```

and then change ownership of subversion repository directory [ not your local copy of it! ] so it's owned by user you found out in fist step

```
chown user: -R /some/path/to/svn/repo
```

btw - i do suggest you make your repository available via [http / libapache2-svn](http://www.progressad.com/unix/svn/svn.html). you'll gain more standardized access method and ability to have fine-grained access control. if you go that way - change ownership of the repository to www-data [ or other user under which apache runs ].